# Can you unit test pipeline code in github actions?

Tags: testing, jenkins-pipeline, cloud, github-actions, devops

I can't find a lot of info on this but basically I would like to replicate [this](https://downloads.ctfassets.net/vtn4rfaw6n2j/jenkinsworld2018-robustunit-testingofpipelinecodewithspock-austi/2e3b55dbb9e053208893bf0de39a7d85/jenkins_world_2018_-_robust_unit-testing_of_pipeline_code_with_spock_-_austin_witt.pdf) on a github workflow. In other words:

How can you write tests for custom actions you have developed in a GH workflow ?

if you use:

```
python => pytest
YAML => checks ?
nodejs => some of the marketplace actions do have tests on them already
bash => ???
```

I usually dont test my pipeline as code stuff, but somebody brought up the good old argument jenkins is better than GH because of testing, whatever that means

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest I can get. if I'll have to validate inputs I could use [The GitHub ToolKit for developing GitHub Actions](https://github.com/actions/toolkit), where I can achieve unit testing in typescript. Couldn't find anything related to python that is actually not supported by github. However, I really don't think it matters since typescript will achieve what I want. I'm open to other ideas if this is wrong

some useful links:

[Create your own github action](https://dev.to/github/generate-your-own-github-action-with-the-actions-toolkit-cli-1lno)

[JS and PR checks](https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-create-a-custom-github-action-with-node-javascript/)

**UPDATE:**

Looks like my initial response wasn't that far from the truth. Here's a good explanation on all types of testing for github actions

[Testing JS GH actions](https://dev.to/cardinalby/testing-of-javascript-actions-20a6)

[Using Typescript](https://radu-matei.com/blog/building-github-actions/)